# Raphaël and D3.JS - Better Browser Compatibility

Tags: raphael, d3.js, protovis

Is it possible to use D3 and Raphael together so that visualizations are produced by D3 (using D3's API to produce svg output) and correctly visualized in IE by Raphael ?

I appreciate any example/sample code.

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can.

We've improved r2d3 from a compatibility project to an IE fallback for D3. This was achieved by having D3 wrap Raphael elements which we extended with methods such as setAttribute. This enables D3 to work with Raphael elements like they were DOM nodes.  The project still needs some work to iron out issues with things like groups, but I encourage you to check it out to see if it meets your needs.

https://github.com/mhemesath/r2d3

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: **No**

**But** you can use the IE-compatible features of D3 to some extend.
Have a look at Jeff Pflueger's [discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/d3-js/Zam9yLhLRA4). And his [conclusion](http://www.jeffpflueger.com/content/d3-data-driven-documents-and-internet-explorer) (includes some code).

Here is another [discussion](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/issues/619), and a good [summary](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/issues/619#issuecomment-5244983) from Mike Hemesath. He uses d3 "to do the heavy lifting of handling the scales, generating path data for areas and lines and formatting dates", and he uses Raphael for the rendering.

He is also maintaining a compatibility project for that, named [r2d3](https://github.com/mhemesath/r2d3).