# D3 bullet chart and ie8

Tags: javascript, raphael, d3.js

I'm using the [bullet chart example of D3](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/ex/bullet.html) with no problem except on IE8 that does not support SVG. So I'm trying to use the Raphael SVG import as mentionned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9559365/raphael-and-d3-js-better-browser-compatibility). But I've hard time to understand how it should work; taking the .html() of the bullet chart is a bit late as IE8 is throwing an error much before during the "rendering" of the bullet chart.

Any solution ? pointer I should look for ?

EDIT : I've just found the following project [d34raphael](http://webmonarch.github.com/d34raphael/). The question is still open for an alternative solution.

Comment: You can try removing all of the animation and see if that gets you any further...

Comment: No success. After a bit of debugging in ie8, the error is generated when trying to add the <svg> node. Anyway, to generate the "svg" into a string to give it later to Raphael importSvg ?

Comment: Ah. I had hoped IE8 would ignore the SVG tag, not throw an error. I can't think of any way around that. There might be some way to append a non-SVG div as your container element, do all your d3 operations, grab the innerHTML, then use a regex to change your container to an SVG string and send it to Raphael SVG import. (Pardon the unhelpful post.)

Answer (score 1):

Try using R2D3. It's a shim to make D3 work in IE7 and 8.

https://github.com/mhemesath/r2d3